# How to get last inserted ID in MessageBox after clicking Submit Button

Tags: c#, auto-increment, messagebox, submit-button

I have this code:

```
private void btnPotvrdi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BCKPSRVR;Initial Catalog=protokol;Integrated Security=True");
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("insert into Knjiga (Datum_prijema, Predmet, Posiljalac, Adresa_posiljaoca, Primaoc, Datum_proslijeda)  values ('" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "');", con);
     int o=sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
     MessageBox.Show(o + " :Podaci su unešeni");
     con.Close();
}
```

When I insert into this table, I have an auto_increment int primary key column called Osnovni_br. How can i get the last value of that column (Osnovni_br) in MessageBox or insted of MessageBox?

Comment: Heard of SQL Injection attacks?

Comment: Beware of Sql injection. You can append `SELECT  SCOPE_IDENTITY();` to your query and use `ExecuteScalar()`, note that it returns a decimal value. I assumed `MSSQL` for no good reason.

Comment: @Silvermind Can you please do an example for my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//read about sql injection here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11020/SQL-injection-attacks
using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=BCKPSRVR;Initial Catalog=protokol;Integrated Security=True"))
      {
          conn.Open();
          using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand())
          {
              cmd.Connection = conn;
              cmd.CommandText = "insert into Knjiga (Datum_prijema, Predmet, Posiljalac, Adresa_posiljaoca, Primaoc, Datum_proslijeda)  values (@Datum_prijema,@Predmet,@Posiljalac,@Adresa_posiljaoca,@Primaoc,@Datum_proslijeda);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Datum_prijema", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
              //.... similarly add other values
              int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
          }
      }
```

Comment: I got this error [PHOTO OF THE ERROR](http://s7.postimg.org/m3nfy683v/error.jpg)

Comment: there was a duplicate in parameter values.. corrected it.

Comment: I did, still the same. 

Caught: "Incorrect syntax near ','."

Comment: OK i got it. But what I also wanted is when I insert all that to open a small windows showing me the last ID value.